# Динамическое создание с++ объектов в QJSEngine

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qml

Не могу разобраться как организовать создание своих объектов в js коде под управлением QJSEngine

пробовол так :
main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include "js_object.h"

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Js_Object*)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QJSEngine myEngine;
    qmlRegisterType<Js_Object>("Js_Object", 1, 0, "Js_Object");
    QJSValue v=myEngine.evaluate("import Js_Object 1.0;\n var t= new  Js_Object() ;");
    qDebug()<<v.toString();
    return a.exec();
}
```

JsObject.h

```
#ifndef JS_OBJECT_H
#define JS_OBJECT_H

#include <QObject>
class Js_Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Js_Object(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
        qDebug()<<"Js_Object::Js_Object(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)";
}
};
#endif // JS_OBJECT_H
```

пример компилируется, но при запуске выдает в консоль

```
"SyntaxError: Syntax error"
```

Подскажите что не так делаю?

Comment: QScriptEngine позволяет делать такие штуки, но он в Qt5.5 объявлен как deprecated, ищу способы перехода с QScriptEngine наQJSEengine

Comment: Кто-нибудь вообще делал подобное??

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что new в javascript'е не создаст Вам плюсовый объект, как Вы ожидаете. Используйте фабрику.

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QJSEngine>
#include <QDebug>

#include "js_object.h"

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Js_Object*)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QJSEngine myEngine;
    Factory *factory = new Factory;
    QJSValue jsFactory = myEngine.newQObject(factory);
    myEngine.globalObject().setProperty("f", jsFactory);
    QJSValue v=myEngine.evaluate("var t = f.create(); t.foo();");
    qDebug() << v.toString();

    return a.exec();
}
```

js_object.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
class Js_Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Js_Object(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
        qDebug()<<"Js_Object::Js_Object(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)";
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE int foo() { qDebug() << "foo called"; return 42; }
};

class Factory : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE QObject* create() {
        return new Js_Object();
    }
};
```

Output:

```
Js_Object::Js_Object(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
foo called
"42"
```

Comment: Фабрика не очень решение, т.к. читаемость JS кода станет хуже, да и эстетически на js код будет не очень смотреться. Хотелось бы сделать по аналогии с QTScript где регистрируется объект, его конструктор и после его можно через new по имени создавать в JS коде